# Counting Distinct Palindromic Substrings

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a string S, I want to count the number of distinct palindromic substrings of S. I know the basic O(n^2) approach to do so. But I want to find a better approach for strings that can be very large (of the order of 10^5).

So I want a more efficient algorithm.

Example:

Say S=xyx, then the palindromic counter must return 3 as answer, as S has three palindromic substrings: {x,xyx,y}.

My code :

```
int countPalindrome(char *str)
{
int i,j,k,count=0;
for(i=0;str[i];i++)
{
    k=i-1;j=i+1;  //count odd length palindromes
    while(k>=0 && str[j] && str[k]==str[j])
    {
        ++count;
        k--;j++;
    }

    k=i;j=i+1; //count even length palindrome
    while(k>=0 && str[j] && str[k]==str[j])
    {
        ++count;
        k--;j++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Clearly its O(n^2) and even does not provide distinct but all palindromes .Can someone provide a better algorithm to count Distinct Palindromic Substrings

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473485/number-of-distinct-palindromic-substrings/20473566

Comment: @AbhishekBansal How to find the number of palindromic substrings in linear time using Manacher's algorithm.?

Comment: You can google for the exact algorithm. It basically builds the substrings from their centre.

Comment: Ya. i knew.Actually suppose b is center of a palindrome substring aabaa then will it take into consideration both the substrings that are aabaa and aba?

Comment: The array maintains just only the length of longest palindromic substring of string S, centered at i

Comment: You can adapt the algorithm for your need as explained in the link I gave.

Comment: It does not contain implementation of Manacher's Algorithm.In the link its assumed that user had implemented it by using the algorithm. That is not the case with me

Comment: @user3086701 seems like online contest problem where u need to optimize.

Comment: No. I need it for a practice problem at SPOJ.

Comment: have a look at http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/Manacher.java.html . Adapt it to your need as @Abhishek pointed.

Comment: @srini I dont want to find longest palindromic substring in linear time but the count of palindromic substrings.How to get it from this algorithm.Please help

Comment: I don't see a way to get this below O(n^2). For each starting index, you *have* to look all the way to the ends of the string, since that could be one.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Some Dp approach can help?